# Textpos on just one page

Tags: textpos

I'm using the [Friggeri CV style](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv), and it's not well-equipped for multiple pages. It has an aside environment, using textpos, which only appears on the first page — but the space for it exists on subsequent pages as well.

```
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\newenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} ##1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection
}
```

I've figured out how to use scrpage2 to customize the page numbers between pages, but I'm not quite sure how to confine the aside spacing to only the first page. Can anyone offer a tip?

Comment: Please post a complete example we can compile to reproduce the problem. However, if the class? package? is really not suited to multi-page documents, wouldn't it be easier to use one which is?

Comment: Probably, which is what I might do. It just means rewriting the whole darn thing. Oh well, thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes :(. Sometimes, though, that is the quickest and easiest strategy in the long run because constantly trying to fit a square document into a round class tends to keep producing more and more difficulties. Every time you manage to solve one problem, a dozen more pop up. [Note that I'm not familiar with the class  you are using so this isn't a comment on that class as such.]

Answer (score 2):

As I found in http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/change-margins-of-a-single-page/ you only have to start a new page and use `\newgeometry` command redefining the new page dimentions.

```
\newpage
\newgeometry{left=2.1cm}
```

\newgeometry